# Laravel 5 - Sessions in Routes

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

**I want to use dynamical routing in Laravel 5** relying on language preferences, not on subdomains/segments. There is a default language and a user can change it (using a GET parameter) even if he is not logged in. The change will remain in session (a registered user can save it). SEO should not be a problem (there is a site default language and the robots should get always that).

**The problem is application session is not available in routes.php** (I suppose due to Laravel design). I would like to use a switch or trans() in routes.php to dynamically create them, but it is not the same session as application.

I have tried with a Service Container, but sessions are not fully working at this point (https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/7933#issuecomment-78175846), so I can't use it to initialize a config variable.

Middleware has been another option, but they are loaded after routes.

Is there any way to use sessions in routes? Have I any (better) alternative to manage this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Middleware are not necessarily loaded after the request has finished. Take a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#defining-middleware

> Whether a middleware runs before or after a request depends on the middleware itself.

If I understand it correctly, you could refer to the appropriate controller using this code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware implements Middleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Perform action

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Although I have not tested this.

That being said, I would still not use the same url serving different contents. At least make use of a canonical url then, to point search crawlers in the right direction.

Comment: I just have tried both (before and after) to test it and they are executed before and after the request, but both after the routing. Maybe I need a different approach.
About the canonical url, you are right, I'll have to use it.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve? Send the user with a different language to a different controller?

Comment: Allow the user to switch to a different language including urls.
For instance, the page http://domain.com/about-us (with content in english) will become in http://domain.com/sobre-nosotros (with content in spanish).
So the urls and the content will be different about the same topic.

Comment: Ah like that. Since I have so little information, I assume that these pages are stored in a database? Why don't you route every page to one controller, which fetches the session and then does a database request based on this session? Like: `'table_'. \Session::get('lang');`

Comment: Yes, most of them are in a database and I use something similar to what you said (a 'Page' generic controller when no specific rule has been found and searches in the database).
But then, I need some more complex pages that need a specific rule in routing such as login, register, profile, contact, help, faq, etc.
So, now I have something like this (in a switch/if or using trans()):
Route::get('contact',    'ContactController@index');
Route::get('contacto',  'ContactController@index');
Again, I need the language to distinguish what rules should I filter (or an alternative).

Comment: I still don't get why you need the session for this. The language is already provided b the URL right, cause 'about-us' is different then 'sobre-nosotros'. You can do two things: put these pages in a database too and let that generic page controller sort it out, or better: create static routes in your routes.php, like this: http://www.codeshare.io/AFTy4. In terms of speed it is favorable to lose the foreaches of course, but this makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: Ok, you're right, but I've forgotten to explain something important. These pages are static links, and I have a function to generate the links automatically through translations and it is also used in routes to avoid duplicity (that's why I needed current language/session). In this way, when I change a segment in a translation file, it would be changed in both routes and links. About database, I feel it's a worse solution being non-editable pages and part of the configuration, but I don't know, maybe I'lI have to rethink it a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to understand your scenario, but I must admit that I don't fully grasp what you are trying to achieve. You provide too little information for me in order to help you out here. Can you maybe post the function you are talking about, the one that generates the links?

Comment: Of course, the app is multipurpose (I'm intending to store more than 1 project there), and the function is a generic one that takes the first part of the url and translate it, but variable data is not translated within the links: linkUrl($translatable_part, $fixed_part='');
You can see it here: [http://www.codeshare.io/SkGU6](http://www.codeshare.io/SkGU6) with an example.
This will allow me to get multi language websites taking advantage of a segment file stored in translations folder and at the same time automatically generate the routes with the same file in that language (using trans).